# Python choose random number in specific interval

Tags: python, random, pygame

So I'm making a PyGame that baseball is falling from up, and users in the bottom have to catch the ball. The balls are falling in a random speed, but I'm having hard time getting balls falling in different speed.

For example, my current code for the ball is:

```
def update(self):
    if self.is_falling:
        """Move the ball down."""
        self.y += random.randint(10, 200) / 100
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Here, when I run the program, the ball is falling in different speed but it's barely different. If I change the number to make it to (10, 20000) / 100 then every ball is dropping very fast. What would be the reason? Seems like random number is not so random. Am I using the function wrong?

I want to make each ball to drop in VERY different speed, such as one is very fast, and the other is very slow. And I would want it to be random number so that users can play with many different speed...

I wondered, if there is random function that I can set with a specific interval between generated random numbers? Or should I try a different approach? And if so, how should I do it?

I am very beginner at Python, so if you can explain it easy as possible, that will be much appreciated!

Comment: try using `import random`; `speed = random.random() * 15` or something similar. `random.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 and you can just multiply it by whatever you want to maximum number to be!

Comment: @Reedinationer So I try that method but I still get the same result. If do it as `random.random() *2` to make it slower, all the balls are slowing down but with very slight difference.. and if I do it as `random.random()*15` then all the ball gets faster, but again, with very slight different speed.

Comment: store the fall speed somewhere to see how different they actually are. its possible that the error is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @Sam Actually, that is a great idea. I started thinking random function is very weird but it could be all me. Thank you!

Comment: @Sarah firstly, `random.random()*15` returns a number between 0 and 15, so it could be increasing the speed by 0.00001 potentially and you'd only know if you were to `print()` the value. Secondly, it depends on the scale of the initial speed. If your ball is going 300 and you increase it by .5 you won't notice it. If it's going .5 and you increase it by 15 it will make your game unplayable. It's up to you to fine tune these parameters

Comment: @Sarah You can also use `random.randint(a, b)` to get only integer values returned. There are also several other random functions for which I refer you to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: @Reedinationer Ah! got it. I didn't know how that function worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is sub-pixel distances.  I think your main problem is your `y` movement.  Look at that equation for `self.y +=`, half the time it will result in a pixel-distance of only a single pixel.  When this is added to the self.rect, rounding (or truncation) will make less-than 1-pixel amounts disappear.  For example, the random integer generated is 99, then divided by 100, is 0.99 of a pixel.  In python `int(0.99)` is zero.  Thus around half of the time, the movement is zero, the other half, movement is only 1 pixel since `int(150/100)` => `1`.  (One in every ~190 moments will be 2 pixels.)

```
def update(self):
    if self.is_falling:
        """Move the ball down."""
        self.y += random.randint(10, 200) / 100
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Also as @6502 points out, this will give a jerky random movement.  It would be better to generate a pixels-per-update speed in the class `__init__`, and stick with that.

```
def __init__( self, ... ):
    ...
    self.fall_speed = random.randint(10, 200)   # pixels per update

def update(self):
    if self.is_falling:
        """Move the ball down."""
        self.y += self.fall_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

I like to make things move based on real-time calculations.  This takes the object speed, and the inter-frame timings to work out how much the object has moved.  I like this because if you want to add gravity (or whatever) into the program, it's easy to calculate the new position.

```
class FallingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A falling sprite.  Falls at a constant velocity in real-time """
    def __init__( self, image ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = image
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.fall_speed  = random.randint(10, 200) # pixels / second
        self.last_update = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )
        self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), 0 )  

    def update( self ):
        # There may have been movement since the last update
        # so calculate the new position (if any)
        if ( self.fall_speed > 0 ):
            time_now    = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )
            time_change = time_now - self.last_update      # How long since last update?
            if ( time_change > 0 ):
                distance_moved   = time_change * self.fall_speed / 1000
                now_x, now_y     = self.rect.center        # Where am I, right now
                updated_y        = now_y + distance_moved
                # Did we fall off the bottom of the screen?
                if ( updated_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
                    # sprite disappears
                    self.kill()
                else:
                    self.rect.center = ( now_x, updated_y )
                    self.last_update = time_now
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the kind detailed answer. I will definitely look into it as a guide and try again!

Answer (score 2):

If this is Python 2 there is a problem with

```
random.randint(10, 200) / 100
```

because the division will be done in integer math.
You should use

```
random.randint(10, 200) / 100.
```

Another problem is that you are choosing the random step at every update (probably every frame) and this will not give the illusion of a speed, but more of a randomly jerky movement.
It would probably be better to choose a random speed like your are doing but keeping it the same at least for a few frames or even for the whole fall animation.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of python which is 3.7 I believe...?

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak the numbers a bit, 20000 is an awfully large jump from 200. As the values you are getting now are 10/100 and 200/100. Which is .1 to 2 pixels, so I don't imagine they would be very different.You jumped to 10/100 to 20000/100, which is a massive speed which is about 200 pixels cap vs the original 2. So that's your issue. Perhaps a range like 200 to 2000 or even 200 to 2500. You don't need such a large tweak as you said the balls began to fall very quickly. I've made the same kind of game before, and I can say that you just need to tweak the numbers slightly.